# Data type mismatch in criteria expression (Access DB)

Tags: c#, sql-update, oledb

My datatype in the Database Table is Short Text and I'm not sure Why I'm getting this error at `command2.ExecuteNonQuery();`

**Error Message**

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll`

`Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`

**My Codes**

```
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand();
cmd1.Connection = con;
cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers Where FirstName=@FirstName OR LastName=@FirstName OR NRIC=@FirstName";
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtSearch.Text);
OleDbDataReader read2 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
string id = "";
while(read2.Read())
{
    id = read2["id"].ToString();
}
OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand();
command2.CommandText = "UPDATE CheckIn_Details SET ModeOfCheckIn='True' WHERE ID='" + id + "'";
command2.Connection = con;
command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What's the data type of `ModeOfCheckIn` & `ID`? The error is obvious: mismatched data type used in second query.

Comment: Opps ment to say ModeOfCheckIn is short text and ID is autonumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ID is AutoNumber then you do not need quotation marks.  Try this instead:

```
command2.CommandText = "UPDATE CheckIn_Details SET ModeOfCheckIn='True' 
WHERE ID=" + id;
```